# MiniKube status

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes and I am from .Net back ground. Windows 10 edition Home OS and I have installed Docker for Desktop in my machine along with Minikube and Kubectl. When I run minikube status command , I get the following message.

****! Executing "docker container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}}" took an unusually long time: 3.2301512s

- Restarting the docker service may improve performance.****
  minikube.
  type: Control Plane.
  host: Running.
  kubelet: Running.
  apiserver: Running.
  kubeconfig: Configured.

I see the same error when I try the command minikube service